# Using Responses from Get Requests to Create New Request

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, get, request

So, I am currently pulling from an API that gives a response like this.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "limit": 20,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 10
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "date": "2019-03-15",
      "id": 16,
      "mSlug": "gud_vs_dex",
      "resource_uri": "/api/v1/match/16/",
      "team1": "/api/v1/team/7/",
      "team2": "/api/v1/team/3/",
      "time": "21:30:00",
      "viewLink": "twitch.tv/tectalparrot198q",
      "viewLink2": null
    },
```

I then need to be able to get five fields from this response - `mSlug`, `team1`, `team2`, `date`, and `time`. I have no problem getting `mSlug`, `date`, and `time`. However, the issue is that I need to use the links returned from `team1` and `team2` to make new GET requests, that return an API that looks like:

```
{
  "captain": "Parrayeet",
  "currentRanking": 100,
  "id": 7,
  "members": "CFE SilentHeart,GreenTigerBeast,Pack Jaul",
  "name": "Guardian Down",
  "platform": "Xbox",
  "resource_uri": "/api/v1/team/7/",
  "slug": "guardian_down"
}
```

From here, I need to be able to get the names of the teams that I am searching for. Finally, in the end, I need to be able to piece together the information from all of the calls to make one string telling the user the team's names (from the second/third calls), and the date/time/link from the first call. However, because the requests are asynchronous, I am unable to save these results to any variable or array, so I can't simply do a

```
slug = response.body.objects[0].mSlug
```

Are there any good ways that I can make multiple GET requests, with some using the response's information, and concatenate the data together at the end? I have tried using `fetch`, `request`, and `request-promise`, all to no avail. Any help (and explanation as to why this works) would help.

Comment: Hi Hunter! I update my answer showing how you can get team1 and team2 url and how you can make the calls. I add a short version of the options just to show you how to change your url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain you promise like this:

```
rp(options)
.then(function (body) {
    idk(body.objects)
    return body     
})
.then(function (value) {
    // do something with value
    makeCall(value.objects)
    idk(body.objects)     
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

After your first promise resolves, you can use return to pass the value to the next .then method.

Comment: So where would I make another get call in here?

Comment: You could do it inside the first .then method if the response from the first promise is enough and if you need you can also return the value from the second promise to the last then method and do some other logic there. Have you used the fetch api. Maybe its simpler.

Comment: i am, although i have no clue how to wrap the secondary requests into the first one. essnetially, the json from the first call returns two links, and i need to go to those two api links and get data from them and print it out...

Comment: Hi Hunter! Check my new answer to see if it is more clear for you know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more clear. Since i am returnig a promise from the makeCall function, you have access to the .then method.

```
makeCall(options).then(res => {
    options = {
        url = "yourendpoint.com" + res.objects[0].team1;
    }
    makeCall(options).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })

    options = {
        url = "yourendpoint.com" + res.objects[0].team2;
    }
    makeCall(options).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })

})


function makeCall(options) {
    return rp(options)
        .then(function (body) {
            return Body     
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
}
```

Or you can await for the promise to resolve, inside of an async function, like this:

```
call();

call = async () => {
    // some logic
    let res = await makeCall(options);
    // do something with response
    // create new options
    let req = await makeCall(options);
}


function makeCall(options) {
    return rp(options)
        .then(function (body) {
            return body     
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return err
        });
}
```